# Referencing more than one method using one delegate

Tags: vb.net, methods, delegates

In C# I used "+=" to reference more than one method to a delegate.
But I tryied it in VB.NET and it didn't work.

This is the example code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Delegate Function delegateSum(a As Integer, b As Integer) As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim s As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum1) 
        s += AddressOf sum2 'Here is the error, that is "Expression does not produce a value"
    End Sub

    Public Function sum1(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + y
    End Function

    Public Function sum2(x As Integer, y As Integer) As Integer
        Return x + y
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: @HansPassant, `AddHandler` is for registering event handlers, not for combining delegates in general.  It requires you to specify the event that you're adding a handler to.

Comment: I'm not really sure why anyone has voted to close this question. It seems fair to me: here's what I want to do, here's how I tried to do it, here's what happened when I tried it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Delegate.Combine` method is what you want:

```
Dim s1 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum1)
Dim s2 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum2)

Dim s As delegateSum = DirectCast([Delegate].Combine(s1, s2), delegateSum)
```

In this case though, there wouldn't be much use in combining delegates.  The point of those two methods is to return a sum but a combined delegate can only return one value so you're only going to get the result of the second method anyway.  You'd more likely combine `Sub`s rather than `Function`s.

By the way, if you wanted to combine more than two delegates then you could do so with a single call or multiple, because `Combine` is overloaded and takes two arguments or a `ParamArray`.

Single call:

```
Dim s1 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum1)
Dim s2 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum2)
Dim s3 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum3)

Dim s As delegateSum = DirectCast([Delegate].Combine(s1, s2, s3), delegateSum)
```

Multiple calls:

```
Dim s1 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum1)
Dim s2 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum2)

Dim s As delegateSum = DirectCast([Delegate].Combine(s1, s2), delegateSum)

Dim s3 As New delegateSum(AddressOf sum3)

s = DirectCast([Delegate].Combine(s, s3), delegateSum)
```